# Dataframe full of strings (w/ some empty strings); would like to to convert some columns to ints, some columns to floats, and keep some as strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe comprised of 14 columns with all cells as strings.

Some of these strings are actual words with letters. I would like to keep these columns as strings (indexes 0, 3, 4, and 13).

Some of these strings are whole numbers with no decimal place.. I would like to convert some columns into ints (indexes 1:2, 5:7, 9:10, 12).

Finally, the remaining strings are numbers with decimal places. I want to convert these remaining columns to floats (indexes 6, 8, 11)

Here's a sample from the dataframe:

```
0  1         2     3   4    5  6   7  8    9  10  11   12    13 

0  Joe Blow  1947  29  CLE  Q  4   1  0.3  4  5   6.5  2.4   Joe.htm
1  Ed Blow   1972  24  HOU  Q  18  1  0.8  4  2   2.5        Ed.htm
2  Jim Blow  1974  23  CHI  Q  18  3  2.2  2      0.8  3.83  Jim.htm  
3  Al Blow   1995      STL  Q  16  2       5  1   3.1  4.5   Frank.htm
4  Tom Blow  1969  23  DET  Q  14  1  0.8  3  0   2.4  4.0   Tom.htm




[5 rows x 14 columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), but if `NaN`s, `int` columns are converted to `float`s because per design:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').combine_first(df)

print (df)
     0     1     2     3    4  5   6  7    8  9   10   11    12         13
0  Joe  Blow  1947  29.0  CLE  Q   4  1  0.3  4  5.0  6.5  2.40    Joe.htm
1   Ed  Blow  1972  24.0  HOU  Q  18  1  0.8  4  2.0  2.5   NaN     Ed.htm
2  Jim  Blow  1974  23.0  CHI  Q  18  3  2.2  2  NaN  0.8  3.83    Jim.htm
3   Al  Blow  1995   NaN  STL  Q  16  2  NaN  5  1.0  3.1  4.50  Frank.htm
4  Tom  Blow  1969  23.0  DET  Q  14  1  0.8  3  0.0  2.4  4.00    Tom.htm

print (df.dtypes)
0      object
1      object
2       int64
3     float64
4      object
5      object
6       int64
7       int64
8     float64
9       int64
10    float64
11    float64
12    float64
13     object
dtype: object
```